# "Invalid Host header" when web app is served inside a VM (Angular2CLI)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine

I am trying to run my web app from inside an Ubuntu 16 64-bit virtual machine. Of course, this means I can't have the `host` be `localhost`, so I changed the host in the `.angular-cli.json` file under `defaults`:

```
"defaults": {
    "serve": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
```

When I do `npm start` and go to the URL of the VM, I get a page saying "Invalid Host header". What am I doing wrong? How can I run the web app and access it correctly?

I am new to Angular and was following this tutorial: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart. I am also using Vagrant.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: changing "serve" to "server" could be a good start, if that is in fact a bug

Comment: "server" is not a recognized property. I believe it has to be "serve".

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to use the `private_network` ip address as the host instead, which is located inside the `Vagrantfile` on this line:

```
# Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
# using a specific IP.
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.5"
```

Though, this only makes it work locally. If someone else has an answer, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

host should be `192.168.0.100` (your ubuntu server ip).

maybe you can just edit `package.json`

add `host` para in start cmd.

```
"start": "*************   --host 192.168.0.100 ",
```

and  npm start will be ok.